# arp response received but ICMP packets are not reaching to own host even

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, network-interface, windows-networking

My environment has 2 hosts and a VM on each host. NVGRE tunnel is created, as VMs and Hosts belongs to different subnets. I am using Windows server 2012 R2 hosts and same VMs. Hosts are connected back to back. If I put VMs and Hosts in same subnet Ping works.

Both the VMs are receiving ARP requests and responses from each other. ARP cache of each VM is having dynamic entry of other VM.

BUT ICMP request packet from VM is not even seen on its Host.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot just ping from one host to another host.
To ping provider address from your host, -p option is needed.

Example:

```
$address = (Get-NetVirtualizationProviderAddress).ProviderAddress
ping -p $address
```

Please put virtualization lookup records when you need more help.
Run following commands as administrator.

```
Get-NetVirtualizationLookupRecord
Get-NetVirtualizationCustomerRoute
```

Also make sure your VM's firewall allows ICMP echo.